# App Service stops writing to DB table after throwing exception

Tags: c#, backend, aspnetboilerplate

Using AspNetBoilerplate. I'm being asked to create a way to provide a user to unsubscribe from a service prior password check which is where I'm stuck.

```
    [AbpAuthorize]
    public class UserCompaniesManagerAppService : InvoiceAppServiceBase, IApplicationService
    {
        public async Task CancelSubscription(CheckPasswordDto input)
        {
            using (CurrentUnitOfWork.SetTenantId(AbpSession.TenantId))
            
            {
                var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();

                //verify pass
                if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, input.Password))
                {
                    await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
                   
                    //TODO: unsubscribe
                }
                else
                {
                    //response from server when wrong password
                    await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);

                    var count = await UserManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
                    var maxAttempts = await SettingManager.GetSettingValueAsync<int>(
                        AbpZeroSettingNames.UserManagement.UserLockOut.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout);
                   
                    throw new UserFriendlyException("tried " + count.ToString() + " left attempts " + (maxAttempts - count).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using "UserFriendlyException" which is what is suggested from docs. I was expecting to see the times wrong password was done and the times left for a correct password. Server response this way.

```
{
  "result": null,
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "tried 1 left attempts 2",
    "details": null,
    "validationErrors": null
  },
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
}
```

Thing is, that if I keep executing it, it stays on those values. Also, the DB doesn't count the failed attempts. No data is written on AbpUsers table.

I've tried using, just in case, `Task<string>` and return the message that way and it works fine, the counters, the fields in AbpUsers and the lockdown. But I know this shouldn't be done this way but to provide an object as a response like throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP's [Conventional Unit of Work](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#conventional-unit-of-work-methods) is scoped around your App Service method `CancelSubscription`:

> if no exception is thrown, it commits the transaction at the end of it. If an exception is thrown, it rolls everything back.

Begin a new unit of work `uow` that gets completed:

```cs
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
    uow.Complete();
}

var count = await UserManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
var maxAttempts = await SettingManager.GetSettingValueAsync<int>(
    AbpZeroSettingNames.UserManagement.UserLockOut.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout);

//response from server when wrong password
throw new UserFriendlyException("tried " + count.ToString() + " left attempts " + (maxAttempts - count).ToString());
```

Alternatively, you can make `AccessFailedAsync` `virtual` and mark it with the `UnitOfWork` attribute:

```cs
[UnitOfWork(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)]
public virtual async Task AccessFailedAsync(User user)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This actually worked for many cases. I had to add flag variables so they will throw the UserFriendlyException after evaluation with if. In certain circumstances, that are not that clear to me, it won't work so tech lead recommended the use of the following:

           using (var _unitOfWorkManager = IocManager.Instance.ResolveAsDisposable<IUnitOfWorkManager>())
            {
                using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Object.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))

It is like it is trying to enforce a module to be used.